# How can I get all the methods in a Protocol?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, pharo

How can I get a collection of all the (class) methods in a given protocol in smalltalk/squeak/pharo?

I'm trying to collect the values returned by a group of methods. I don't want to have to store the methods in an instance or class variable. So I though I could add them to a protocol and in this way to "mark" them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Pharo, the method you're looking for is `ClassDescription>>allMethodsInCategory:`:

```
| selectors |
selectors := MyClass allMethodsInCategory: #'protocol name'.
```

To find methods in a class-side protocol, just send to the metaclass instead:

```
selectors := MyClass class allMethodsInCategory: #'protocol name'.
```

Another solution you might want to consider, though, is to use a pragma to mark your methods instead.  See the comment on the `Pragma` class for details of that approach.  It has the advantages that other packages can freely add methods belonging to your group (which need to be in a * protocol), and that the pragma can be used to store other metadata as well (such as an evaluation order, for example).

**NB.** The selector `allMethodsInCategory:` has been deprecated in Pharo 3.0 and later in favor of `allSelectorsInProtocol:`